# Instalacion Numpy(OK) pero Pandas(NOK)

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo instalado Python 3.7 y numpy-1.16.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl pero cuando intento instalar pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl me aparece el error "Could not find a version that satifies the requirement pytz......No matching distribution found for pytz>=2011k "

pip3 install numpy-1.16.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl -> OK
pip3 install pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl -> NOK ¿Porque?

¿Alguien puede indicarme que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Esos requisitos de versiones tan concretas son necesarias? No te valdría hacer un `pip 3 install numpy pandas` sin especificar versiones y que `pip` coja las compatibles? (que serán las más recientes posibles para tu versión de python y plataforma)

Comment: También puedes probar a hacer un `pip3 install --pre pytz>=2011k` para forzar a pip a que admita versiones "pre-release" (que por defecto no acepta), y así te instale esa versión de pytz que te está dando problemas. Una vez hecho eso, probar a instalar de nuevo pandas.

Comment: El error indica que pip no puede obtener pytz (dependencia de Pandas) en PyPi. pytz va  por la versión 2019.1 (las nombran por el año de salida) y no usa código C que necesite ser compilado (por lo que es indiferente el sistema y la arquitectura (Windows 32 bits en tu caso)) por lo que no debería pasar esto ¿Por qué usas el archivo wheel directamente? ¿Quieres instalar sin conexión o tuviste otros problemas para instalar desde PyPi? . Siempre puedes descargar el whl e instalarlo antes de Pandas https://pypi.org/project/pytz/#files. Si no tienes pip actualizado te recomiendo  actualizarlo.

Comment: Tuve problemas instalando directamente (pip3 install pandas numpy) y enconrtré que podría instalarse con .whl así que probé ese camino. Para instalar numpy me funcionó pero con pandas tengo el problema que os comento.